# JQuery idTabs - problems with hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I have simple html page with 3 tabs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>idTabs</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
</head><body style="background-color:White; color:Black">

    <style type="text/css">
        /* Jquery Tabbed Panels */
        div.idTabs
        {
        float:left;
        margin-top:30px;
        }

        .idTabs a
        {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #333;
            background: #DDF1FF;
            font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: none;
        }

        .idTabs a.selected
        {
            background: #FFF;
            color: #333;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
            z-index: 120;
        }

    </style>
    <div class="vi_wrapper">

        <div class="idTabs">
            <ul style=" padding: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 100;">
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a class="selected" href="#Tab1" name="Tab1">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a href="#Tab2" name="Tab2">Tab2</a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a href="#Tab3" name="Tab3">Tab3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="items">
                <div id="Tab1">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab1
                        <br />
                        here is hash, and when you click on it - no tab:
                        <br />
                        <a href="#SomeHashTab1">Some Hash 1</a>                        
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div id="Tab2">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab2
                        <br />

                        here is hash, and when you click on it - no tab:
                        <br />
                        <a href="#SomeHashTab2">Some Hash 2</a>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="Tab3">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".idTabs").idTabs(true, location.hash);
        </script>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

So, each tab opens by hash in the link (#Tab1, #Tab2, #Tab3), but if I add some other link with hash into tab content, it opens me an empty tab.

How can I skip the clicks on all hashes that are not of tab hash?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `items` DIV ***outside*** the `idTabs` DIV. It seems that the plugin binds the tabs effect on **all** the links that contains hashes.

**EDIT:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><title>idTabs</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
</head><body style="background-color:White; color:Black">

    <style type="text/css">
        /* Jquery Tabbed Panels */
        div.idTabs
        {
        float:left;
        margin-top:30px;
        }

        .idTabs a
        {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #333;
            background: #DDF1FF;
            font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: none;
        }

        .idTabs a.selected
        {
            background: #FFF;
            color: #333;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #FFF;
            z-index: 120;
        }

        .items {
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="vi_wrapper">
        <div class="tabs-cont">
        <div class="idTabs">
            <ul style=" padding: 0px; position: relative; z-index: 100;">
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a class="selected" href="#Tab1" name="Tab1">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a href="#Tab2" name="Tab2">Tab2</a>
                </li>
                <li style="display: block; list-style: none; float: left; background: #CCC; padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px; margin-right:4px;">
                    <a href="#Tab3" name="Tab3">Tab3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="items">
                <div id="Tab1">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab1
                        <br />
                        here is hash, and when you click on it - no tab:
                        <br />
                        <a href="#SomeHashTab1">Some Hash 1</a>                        
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div id="Tab2">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab2
                        <br />

                        here is hash, and when you click on it - no tab:
                        <br />
                        <a href="#SomeHashTab2">Some Hash 2</a>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="Tab3">
                    <div style="float:left">
                        Tab3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".idTabs").idTabs(true, location.hash);
        </script>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I removed it ("items" div) completely, but it doesn't resolve it, problem still exists

Comment: @ihorko: I meant moving it with **all** its contents!

Comment: If I move I will not have a tabs. Or I don't understand something, please post a code here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(location.hash).length) {
   $(".idTabs").idTabs(true, location.hash);
}
```

**EDIT:** Not `'#'+location.hash`, because `location.hash` already includes a `'#'`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, same problem, when you click on "Some Hash 1" it clears all tabs, and show nothing (no tab)

Comment: hm, its possible if block with id `somehash1` exists

Comment: no, it doesn't, just create 1.html file on disc, copy my code above into that file and open it in browser, you will see